# Android:problem in remember me functionality of login Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

i have create login page with 2 EditText and checkbox and login button.
if i set checkbox to Enabled i want to save data so next time user doesn't need to fill that fields..
i have uses this code but no luck..

public class LoginPage extends Activity {

```
EditText d_ID;
EditText password;
CheckBox cb;
ImageButton ib;

public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
public String PREFS_USER;
public String PREFS__PASS;
String username;
String upass;
```

SharedPreferences pref

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.loginpage);

    d_ID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dulzuID);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dulzuPASS);

    cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.remember);

    ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.login);






        pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        username = pref.getString(PREFS_USER, null);
        upass = pref.getString(PREFS__PASS, null);
        d_ID.setText(username);
        password.setText(upass);




    ib.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

            startActivity(new Intent(LoginPage.this, Features.class));
        }
    });

    cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton cb1, boolean bln) {

                PREFS_USER = d_ID.getText().toString();//get user name from EditText
                PREFS__PASS = password.getText().toString();//get user Password from EditText
                getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString(PREFS_USER, username).putString(PREFS__PASS, upass).commit();

        }
    });

}
```

}

Any help??

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confusing the variables for retrieving the value of the users password and the variables that identify the username/password values in the preferences.  I *think* that you intend these:

```
public String PREFS_USER;
public String PREFS__PASS;
```

to be the identifiers for your stored username and password, however you then **set** them to be the *values* that you have pulled from the corresponding `EditTexts`.  I have rewritten some of the code for you:

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
public static final String PREFS_USER = "prefsUsername";
public static final String PREFS__PASS = "prefsPassword";
...
pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
username = pref.getString(PREFS_USER, "");
upass = pref.getString(PREFS__PASS, "");
...
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton cb1, boolean bln) {
    username = d_ID.getText().toString();//get user name from EditText
    upass = password.getText().toString();//get user Password from EditText
    getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString(PREFS_USER, username).putString(PREFS__PASS, upass).commit();
}
```

Personally, I wouldn't do it like that though.  I would check the value of the checkbox when the user submits the form, and only save the username & password at that point.  What if the user unchecks and then rechecks the tick box **before** they have entered their password?  You will save empty values and annoy your users.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing small mistake in this part:

```
if (cb.isChecked()) {

    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    username = pref.getString(PREFS_USER, null);
    upass = pref.getString(PREFS__PASS, null);
    d_ID.setText(username);
    password.setText(upass);

}
```

As your view is rendered each time when new activity starts.cb.isEnabled() will always give false because it is not enabled that time.

You can do stuff for your sol like this.

```
     SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
if(!pref.getstring(PREFS_USER,null).equals(null)||!pref.getstring(PREFS_USER,null).equals(""))        
{username = pref.getString(PREFS_USER, null);

        d_ID.setText(username);}
   and same for password field
```

Comment: I think CheckBoxes are enabled by default. Unless you disable it.

Comment: oh sorry my mistake.it shuold b ischecked().

Answer (score 2):

One thing that I would like to tell you: do not store the values when user clicks on check box save it when user presses login button.

If user clicked that check box when he has not entered details the you will save null values.

And why don't you serialize both the objects and save it to memory and again deserialize it when you need to read it?

```
public void serializeCredentials(String Username,String Password) {
            try {
                FileOutputStream fStream = openFileOutput(namefile.bin, Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ;
                ObjectOutputStream oStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fStream);
                oStream.writeObject(Username) ;
                FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(passwordfile.bin, Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ;
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                oos.writeObject(Password) ;
                oStream.flush() ;
                oStream.close() ;
                oos.flush() ;
                oos.close() ;
                Log.v("Serialization success", "Success");
            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.v("IO Exception", e.getMessage());
            }
            }
```

Don't forget to deserialize when reading data; you can deserialize it similarly.

Comment: Agreed, but this looks more horny :-P saving the encrypted username/password in the SharedPreferences will be good idea according to me.

Comment: Is it so...ok then you have another way 2. This was also one of the way.........lolzzzz

Comment: Serializing that stuff is way overkill here.

Comment: i just wanted 2 highlight that there is 1 more way of doing this.  
"DER ISS ALWAZ AN ALTERNATIVE WAY OF DOIN THINGSSSS"

Answer (score 1):

I think **you need to write/initialize this line inside onCreate() method**.

```
SharedPreferences pref; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.loginpage);

   pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
  ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try doing the editing line by line.. at least in my case, it did the trick..

```
cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton cb1, boolean bln) {

            PREFS_USER = d_ID.getText().toString();//get user name from EditText
            PREFS__PASS = password.getText().toString();//get user Password from EditText

            SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            prefEditor.putString(PREFS_USER, username);
            prefEditor.putString(PREFS__PASS, upass);
            prefEditor.commit();
    } 
});
```

And it would be much better if you follow N-JOY's suggestion to trigger saving data to SharedPreferences during login button click..