# Security in mobile application

Tags: android

In case the user login to app and then switch to other app without logout, how we manage the remember of the credential so once the user back to the previous application he don't need to type credential details again (user/pass)- (Please provide answer with theory also)

Comment: You get idea from answer or not?

Answer (score 1):

Define some statics to store the preference file name and the keys you're going to use:

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
private static final String PREF_USERNAME = "username";
private static final String PREF_PASSWORD = "password";
```

You'd then save the username and password as follows:

```
getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE)
    .edit()
    .putString(PREF_USERNAME, username)
    .putString(PREF_PASSWORD, password)
    .commit();
```

So you would retrieve them like this:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE);   
String username = pref.getString(PREF_USERNAME, null);
String password = pref.getString(PREF_PASSWORD, null);

if (username == null || password == null) {
//Prompt for username and password
}


Alternatively, if you don't want to name a preferences file you can just use the default:


SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Comment: Thanks hardik for your reply, can you provide some link related to this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386311/how-to-use-remember-me-function-in-my-android-login-application, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871616/androidproblem-in-remember-me-functionality-of-login-activity

Comment: This password storage is really not good, please use at least a password'hash (with MD5 for example) before storing this data.

Comment: @grattmandu03 yeh you are also right. post your answer. and plz read question again. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `applicationPreference` for storing the username and password. Google for it, you can easily get the code for it. But for security reason, always try to save such information in encrypted form. And while retrieving info from applicationPrefernces, you have to decrypt it. here is link http://www.androidsnippets.com/encryptdecrypt-strings